# prettyPhoto not working in Chrome and IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, prettyphoto

Hey I'm trying to do a simple popup in prettyPhoto, but getting errors in IE9 and Chrome.

I've upgraded to the latest version of prettyPhoto and the latest jquery, nothing changed.
Also tried using jQuery in noConflict mode, but that didn't work either.

This is the errors in the respective consoles:

IE:

```
SCRIPT5007: Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected 
jquery-1.8.0.min.js, line 2 character 2299
```

Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'marginTop' in undefined jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2
```

and my prettyPhoto script is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
            autoplay: true,
            wmode: 'opaque',
            theme: 'facebook',
            deeplinking: false,
            social_tools: false
        });
    });
</script>`
```

I've looked around everywhere for a solution to this, can't find anything!
Anyone had this issue before?

Comment: ... can you put together a jsfiddle of this? Are you using compressed or uncompressed version of prettyPhoto? Did you try gathering any info  from prettyPhoto (forum, mailing list, etc.)?

Comment: Can we at least see the associated html?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same bug with my own script.

It seems that there's a bug in new jQuery 1.8.0.

Try to switch back to jQuery 1.7.2 - it worked for me.